# Layout not functioning on one of the pages

Tags: android, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I use ionic's grid on most pages, and it works fine. However, on `contacts` page, it fully collapses on an Android.

Tried uploading pictures here but they were oversized. Can be viewed on [ionic forum though](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/grid-doesnt-work-on-android/12586)

Basically in the browser and most other windows, grid works. But on that one page, it doesnt work on Android but is fine in browser. If rows didnt work at all, that would make sense, but only 1 page!

Code:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'state.substr(1,2)'" type="item-text-wrap" ng-class="{{friend.state}}"  href="#/tab/friend/{{friend.id}}">
    <div  class="row">
        <div class="col-75">
            {{friend.name}} <br>
            <h6>{{friend.group}}<h6>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
             <i class="icon ion-flag {{friend.state}}"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
            <label class="toggle toggle-assertive">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="friend.ban">
                <div class="track">
                    <div class="handle"></div>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>

    </div>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML snippet :

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'state.substr(1,2)'" type="item-text-wrap" ng-class="{{friend.state}}"  href="#/tab/friend/{{friend.id}}">
    <div  class="row">
        <div class="col-75">
            {{friend.name}} <br>
            <h6>{{friend.group}}<h6>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
             <i class="icon ion-flag {{friend.state}}"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label class="toggle toggle-assertive" style="float:right;margin-right:5px;">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="friend.ban">
                <div class="track">
                    <div class="handle"></div>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>

    </div>
</ion-item>
```

> Basically, putting col-10 places your second column immediately after the first column. So, we instead remove the explicit column sizing and float the entire content inside the column to the right.

Comment: even worse, it is floating over the text now

Comment: Please put up a plunker for better visualization of your problem

Comment: Clearly cant, as it works fine in a browser. But not on an actual live device